# Programmatically determine text visibility in PDF document

Tags: pdf, itext

Using iTextSharp or some other library, is it possible to determine if a given part of the text is visible?

Using other word, is it possible to extract (to simple text) only the visible parts?

For example, if a given text segment has its font color white, then that text segment would be invisible when printing or displaying on screen.

My goal is to find a way to extract only the text that would be visible when printing that document!

Comment: The amount of work required for that depends on how correct even in complex situations you want to be. How much work are you ready to invest?

Comment: This is not mission critical, and the investment is as small as possible! Some error tolerance exists.

Comment: If *the investment is* to be *as small as possible,* I would not start this sub-project at all. Unless you know your documents well enough to tell which mechanisms are used in case of your invisible characters (non-printing optional content groups, invisible rendering mode, covered by image, ...), the investment wont be small.